# Bayesian meta-analytic t tests - mix one- and two-sample (BayesFactor)

Tags: r, bayesian

The `BayesFactor` package offers a function to estimate a Bayes Factor for a meta-analytic t-test (`meta.ttestBF`). The procedure is based on an article by Rouder and Morey (2011; [link](https://richarddmorey.github.io/BayesFactor/#RouderMetat)).

`meta.ttestBF` can be used to get a Bayes Factor for a series of "one- and two-sample designs." I assume this refers to paired and independent t-tests.

My question is if there is a way to mix t values from one-sample and two-sample designs. Let's assume I have four studies. Three of them use a two-sample design, and one uses a one-sample design. If all of them were of the same type, it would be easy:

```
t <- c(-.15, 2.39, 2.42, 2.43)
N1 <- c(100, 150, 97, 99)
N2 <- c(100, 150, 97, 99)

# One-sample
meta.ttestBF(t = t, n1 = N1)

# Two-sample
meta.ttestBF(t = t, n1 = N1, n2 = N2)
```

So, what should I do if t values 1 to 3 are from a two-sample t-test and t value 4 is from a one-sample t-test?

Comment: Is this a question about coding, or is it about statistical methods?

Comment: Well, it's about applying a statistical method in R. I therefore assumed it fits best here.

Comment: I'm not familiar bayes factor or metastudy methods, but your question appeared to be about whether (or how) one can perform a [partially paired t-test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25941/t-test-for-partially-paired-and-partially-unpaired-data).

Comment: It did not really answer my question but thanks a lot for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered this question here: https://github.com/richarddmorey/BayesFactor/issues/122. The short answer is "not really, because effect sizes have different interpretations in the two models."

Comment: Thanks a lot Richard!